# Objective C strange if (NO) condition

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I have facing a strange issue in Objective C. Please look at the code below.

```
+(BOOL)isWritableCopyofAppConfig{

BOOL response = false;

NSURL *urlConfig = [NSURL URLWithString:APP_CONFIG_PATH];
NSData *dataReturn = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlConfig];
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AppConfig.plist"];

if (dataReturn != nil ){
   // It always goes here
}
else{
   // Never reach here.
}

return response;
}
```

Even if I change the above if condition to the following:

```
if (NO){
   // It always goes here even if there is NO.
}
else{
   // Never reach here.
}
```

I tried cleaning the project i tried other things like directly comparing NO == YES still it goes inside the first block.

Does anyone knows how to solve this or what is this behavior?

**EDIT: The entire code**

```
+(BOOL)isWritableCopyofAppConfig{

BOOL response = false;

NSURL *urlConfig = [NSURL URLWithString:APP_CONFIG_PATH];
NSData *dataReturn = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlConfig];
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AppConfig.plist"];

if (NO){
    if (filePath != nil){
        response = [dataReturn writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
}
else{
    NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AppConfig" ofType:@".plist"];
    [fileMgr copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:filePath error:nil];
}

return response;
```

}

Its a class method (called from AppDelegate.m):

```
 AppConfigHandler.isWritableCopyofAppConfig();
```

**EDIT: Screenshot of debugger**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that it's `if (NO)` not `if(@NO)`?

Comment: Show the exact code, copy and paste, include details on how you're testing it

Comment: how do you know it's taking the _NO_ branch?

Comment: would you, please, share your _real_ code? that current one does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @Cy-4AH, yes its NO.

Comment: @Wain, i have added addition code from where it is called and the exact method.

Comment: @nielsbot, i am sure that it is taking me to NO branch because i can see the debugger going there. Loot at the screen shot.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense unless you've redefined `NO`...

Comment: try adding log statements in both branches of the if statement. seems to me this might just be a debugger glitch

Comment: @DanielGalasko might have a point.. try a clean build?

Comment: What if you command-click on NO?

Comment: Maybe some one have redefined `NO`. What will open if you cmd+click on `NO`?

Comment: @Cy-4AH no there is redefinition.

Comment: @nielsbot i tried to clean several time including remove derived data and restarting the machine.

Comment: @DanielGalasko still no luck.

Comment: @Sudhir my suggestion is to create a new Xcode project and test if you get the same result. I think someone might have been sneaky and overwritten the definition of BOOL or something

Comment: Can you upload your project somewhere? (Or the smallest amount that still shows the problem)

Comment: Back to the original code,  the variable "dataReturn" will never be nil because you instantiate it with [NData dataWith...]

Comment: @itinance yes that's true that condition is wrong. So, for testing purpose to check the code in the else condition i replaced it with NO. Strangely, that was a time when i came to know this issue.

Comment: @DanielGalasko when i did that by creating new project it worked fine without any issue. I dont know what's happening here. Anyway that is not important but this question was raised out of curiosity.

Comment: @nielsbot when i did that by creating new project it worked fine without any issue. I dont know what's happening here. Anyway that is not important but this question was raised out of curiosity.